Ensure Qt handles all message and update all properties
On the project I am working for we have a nice homebrew automated UI testing framework. The main application written in Qt/QML. Automated tests run in another process, connect to the application via gRPC/socket based layer, and provide possibility to click on Qt elements, and read/write their properties.
The approach is excellent, and works for 99% of scenarios like "interact with a UI element, and check that other UI element changed its value/state/contents/etc". Unfortunately there is an issue happening sometimes.
So, imagine an application that has a button, and a list. Clicking the button adds an element to the list. There is a test that checks the following scenario:

click the button
check that 'count' property of the list advances

On some of the machines this test passes well. But there are machines that are more powerful than others, and the test reads 'count' property before it gets its new value.
There is an obvious solution - add a sleep() call between pressing the button and reading properties. This works fine for a single test, but in case of hundreds tests this really slows down test execution (note that the application has more than 1 button and 1 list - it has plenty of other controls, and adding sleeps at all these places may significantly increase test execution time. Even adding a 0.5s sleep at a critical point slowed down test execution 3 times).
So the question: is there a way to determine whether Qt finished updating all the properties associated with the change? Maybe there is an 'idle' flag, that indicates that all ongoing messages in the event queue are processed?

Use a counter in your main app to maintain the finished signals count - Reset the counter when you begin triggering actions from your test app. In your main app connect the objects finished signal to a slot that increments the counter. From your test app check the counter value, if it matches the number of actions taken, you may proceed to read and verify the values from main app.

Use a counter in your main app to maintain the finished signals count.
Reset the counter when you begin triggering actions from your test app.
In your main app connect the objects finished signal to a slot that increments the counter.
From your test app check the counter value, if it matches the number of actions taken, you may proceed to read and verify the values from main app.

What means 'finished signals count'. That is actually what the main question is about - how to understand all updates are finished. Imagine a slightly improved scenario: Button opens a modal dialog, and upon dialog closure the list updates somehow. How do I know that dialog has closed, and the list properties (count, contents) is updated?

Finished signal - Signal emitted from the place where the property is actually updated. In your scenario, emit the finished signal(s) from the place where your list's properties are updated.
